# Can you buy ammo for other players in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

When purchasing ammo at the ammo box in co-op, will other players also receive the ammo?

Comment: Answer: No - only the ammo that is picked up in the world itself will be shared. 

(FYI I don't have the rep yet to answer this myself)

Comment: I posted your answer myself, as a community wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - only the ammo that is picked up in the world itself will be shared